# Converção de STRING, WriteProcessMemory()

Tags: c++

Tenho a seguinte situação, o usuário deve digitar um endereço de memória:

**(ESTOU USANDO ESTE MÉTODO, PODE NÃO SER O CORRETO PARA A SEGUINTE SITUAÇÃO)**

```
std::string TEMP_MEMORY_ADDRESS;
std::string MEMORY_ADDRESS = "0x";
std::cout << "Digite o endereco de Memoria: ";
std::getline(std::cin, TEMP_MEMORY_ADDRESS);
MEMORY_ADDRESS.append(TEMP_MEMORY_ADDRESS);
```

Beleza, agora temos o endereço de memoria solicitado pelo usuário e em Hexadecimal, o problema é: 
tenho que jogar este endereço na função WriteProcessMemory(), e segundo a **MICROSOFT** 
esse endereço precisa estar nos seguintes parametros:

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteProcessMemory(

      _In_   HANDLE hProcess,
      _In_   LPVOID lpBaseAddress,
      _In_   LPCVOID lpBuffer,
      _In_   SIZE_T nSize,
      _Out_  SIZE_T *lpNumberOfBytesWritten
    );
```

lpBaseAddress[in] = **Um ponteiro para o endereço de base no processo especificadas em que os dados são gravados**

Nesta pergunta, a minha dúvida vai apenas para **LPVOID lpBaseAddress** que é onde precisamos encaixar o endereço de memoria digitado pelo usuário, e é ai que entra meu problema:
O método que estou utilizando não esta dando certo quando jogo a string no lpBaseAddress.

**EXEMPLO:**

```
int isSuccessful = WriteProcessMemory(hproc, (LPVOID)MEMORY_ADDRESS.c_str(), &NewValue, (DWORD)sizeof(NewValue), NULL);
```

Tentando jogar na saída de dados o que tinha em **(LPVOID)MEMORY_ADDRESS.c_str()** percebi que tinha um valor aleatório, e não era exatamente o endereço que tinha fornecido.

parece sim uma dúvida boba, mais estou tendo dificuldades em como devo fornecer o valor exato do endereço de memória para a função **WriteProcessMemory();**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa converter a string hexadecimal digitada pelo usuário em um inteiro antes de passar para a função. Da forma como você fez, o que está sendo passado é o *endereço* da string hexadecimal e não o *valor* correspondente.

Para converter a string hex para decimal você pode usar a função [stoul](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee404871.aspx).

Tente assim:

```
unsigned long mem_addr = std::stoul(MEMORY_ADDRESS, NULL, 16);
int isSuccessful = WriteProcessMemory(hproc, (LPVOID)mem_addr, &NewValue, (DWORD)sizeof(NewValue), NULL);
```

<sub>PS.: Estou um tanto enferrujado em WinAPI e C++. Segundo as pesquisas e testes que fiz aqui isso parece que vai funcionar, mas não tive como testar.</sub>

Comment: Muito obrigado camarada, parece coisa boba, mais ajudo bastante!